# Keyframes - direct, shorter shortcut?

Tags: keyframes, shortcut

I am new to blender and I am trying to figure out if instead of hitting "i" ("s" for industry compatible shortcuts), and then having to hover with mouse and chose "all channels" etc, I can have just one, single button on my keyboard that will do that?

Thanks!

Comment: You can most certainly reassign or assign a new key, for some functionality it's a bit more to do though. The "all channels"  you mention would be the "LocRotScale" right?

Comment: I'm not going to _answer_ with this, because definitely not my area. Maybe someone else will.. but I think you might be looking for [Key Sets](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/keyframes/keying_sets.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign a key that always inserts the **LocRotScale** key at the current time, you have to do the following:

1. Go in the **Blender Preferences**, under **Keymap** and search for "Insert Keyframe".
2. There will be an entry under **Outliner**, unfold the "Insert Keyframe" by clicking on the small triangle in front of the checkbox.
   [image]
3. You need to copy the "anim.keyframe_insert" for your own new "one button function"
4. Clear the search and open/unfold the **User Interface** keymappings.
5. At the bottom of the list you will find a button "+ Add New", click that and it should look like this, a new keymap line with "none" set in it
   [image]
6. Where there is "none" you paste the "anim.keyframe_insert", and once you confirm it, the keymap changes to this:
   [image]
7. There is a darkened "Keying Set:" and a "Confirm Successful Insert" that needs some attention. Select the "LocRotScale" in the dropdown-menu of the "Keying Set" and unhook the "Confirm Successful Insert" option, it should now look like this:
   [image]
8. Now there is only one thing left, assigning a key (hopefully not used yet) to have the functionality per "one button".
9. For that just click on the big button right beside the "anim.keyframe_insert" textfield and then press a key. You can afterwards add some modifiers like "Alt", "Ctrl" .. etc.
10. When done, you can test it without having to close the **Blender Preferences** to adjust it or find a better key.

Happy Blending

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it  helped a bit - I didn't realize until now that I can tweak the darker menu options under it, so thanks!

Another thing that I found out is that it is different wherever you are pointing the mouse at the canvas/view port area or at the dopesheet/timeline/graph editor menu, when you are pressing the insert key shortcut. SO I'll add to your well-described tutorial, that the same steps you can do for the different areas (menu to point at when performing the shortcut) when you go through the drop down options under keymapping. Or in other words, when you search "Insert keyframe" at the keymapping, it shouws you basically all possible places your cursor can be when performing the shortcut (at least this is my observation). And also, I previously cleaned up the existing comand for that shortcut, so it won't confuse blender.

Thanks!!!! <3